# How to optimize the fees for cross-chain transfers

Tags: parachain, cross-chain

When we tested the cross-chain transfer, we found that the fee was a bit high. How to optimize various parameters to reduce the transfer fee

such as: parachain A(tokenA) <=> parachain B(tokenB), my parachain is A,how to reduce the cost of cross-chain transfer of tokenB to parachain A, and the cost of tokenB back to parachain B from parachainA.

those parameters will directly affect the cross-chain transfer fee？

Comment: FYI: There’s a fee reduction to reduce teleport fees from kusama to statemine in v800 of the statemine runtime.

Comment: What fee was high? On your chain? Relaychain? The other chain?

Comment: Please provide more detail so the question can be answered: What was the final fee? What fee did you expect? What did the transfer transaction look like? Across which chains?

Answer (score 1):

One reason for too high fees can be because parachains are using:

```
type Trader = UsingComponents<IdentityFee, ..>;
```

You can see in [statemint here](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/d68e9bf27b38fff296ea9f57124d5f9b309018c3/polkadot-parachains/statemint/src/xcm_config.rs#L170) for example that this was recently changed to:

```
    type Trader =
        UsingComponents<WeightToFee, ..>;
```

Typically parachains don't need to charge as much as the relay chain for fees.

(Associated issue: https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/issues/920 )